# Unexpected Regex Result

Tags: c#, regex

I'm attempting to pull a number associated with a username. Each username has a particular value next to it.

private void queryUsers()
        {

```
        string browserText = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
        Match match = Regex.Match(browserText, "(>pickles</a></td><td>).*(</td><td align=\"center\">)");

        string id = match.ToString();
        string clean_id = Regex.Replace(id, @"\D", "");
        textBox1.AppendText(clean_id);

    }
```

The document I'm searching through is of the following format...

```
<tr><td>17.</td><td>ab</td><td><a href="http://www.*****.com/s.php?id=500000">pickles</a></td><td>150,000</td><td align="center"></td></tr>

<tr><td>18.</td><td>cd</td><td><a href="http://www.*****.com/s.php?id=7245658">donuts</a></td><td>250</td><td align="center"></td></tr>
```

I was expecting the result to be "150000". However that is not the case, it creates a huge number starting at 150000 and then combines all the other numbers afterwards.

I'm pretty unfamiliar with regex but a similar solution worked in other spots for me. Am I overlooking something simple, or is there a better way about going about this?

Comment: Don't use regex to parce HTML

Answer (score 0):

.* is greedy and will match all characters so the match will be a huge multiline match. you will need to describe the number as "numbers, comma, numbers" not "0 to millions of anycharacter"

so instead of

```
.*
```

use

```
([0-9]+,)?[0-9]+
```

or something.

or use some kind of a negative lookahead to make sure you will not accidentally match the <. Also if the source material is valid xml or html, use an xml or html parser to parse it.